# Find objects with a specific class in Scene in Unity

Tags: unity, scene

I need to find every object of the same class in the scene. How can I do this?

Comment: Please refrain from filling your question with the same sentence repeated over and over.

Comment: @JoshPetrie, I do not know what to try and that is the reason I am asking here. lol

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to get them in an array with something like FindObjectsOfType.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectsOfType.html

Are you needing some specific functionality that this doesn't offer?